# I-95 Carolina Hurricane Florence Highway Closures

Tags: usa, driving, event-based-effects, maps

Hurricane Florence has damaged many roads in NC \ SC.  I would like to drive from Florida to Washington DC: the normal route is I-95.  Is there an updated service (ideally with the Google Maps platform) that identifies where I-95 is damaged or impassable on a Map?

Any questions or edits to sharpen the question is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The [North Carolina Department of Transportation](https://www.ncdot.gov/Pages/default.aspx) is the official source for that state.  There is a page with [real-time road closure information](https://tims.ncdot.gov/tims/).  This indicates that I-95 is currently closed between I-40 and I-74, except for a short stretch northeast of Fayetteville.

The [South Carolina Department of Transportation](https://www.scdot.org/) also has an [interactive road conditions map](https://scdot.maps.arcgis.com/apps/MapSeries/index.html?appid=f89dbb607181411b86e999ed2897fb21).  This indicates that a stretch of I-95 is closed roughly between Dillon and Florence.